# Facebook PHP SDK 3.0 - cancel_url

Tags: php, facebook

I have my facebook app in a tab on my facebook page. If you are a new visitor, the iframe application asks for the permmision. And if I cancel this authorization I wanna redirect user to my facebook page. Is it possible? The old SDK used cancel_url or something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
     if(isset($_REQUEST['error'])) {
         header('Location: ' . $your_facebook_page);
     }
```

if the user don't allows permission facebook will redirect him to your redirect_uri from there u can see if there is an error and the redirect the user

EDIT:

sorry i forgot it's an iframe app so instead of `header('Location: ' . $your_facebook_page);`
use this `echo '<script>top.location.href="' . $your_facebook_page . '"</script>';`